Должны ли значения по умолчанию для DTO быть вынесены в отдельный класс с константами?
У меня есть DTO-класс, в котором используются значения по умолчанию:
public class OverdueInfoDto
{
    public int? TotalOverdueDays { get; set; } = 1;
    public int? MaxOverdueDays { get; set; } = 100000;
    public int? FromSum { get; set; } = 100000;
    public int? ToSum { get; set; } = 100000;


}

Эти значения используются еще в одном месте в коде. Стоит ли их вынести в отдельный класс с константами, например OverdueDefaults
public static class OverdueDefaults
{
    public const int DefaultOverdueDays = 1;
    public const int DefaultMaxOverdueDays = 100000;
    public const int DefaultFromSum = 1;
    public const int DefaultToSum = 100000;
} 

и сделать класс Dto вот таким
  public  class OverdueInfoDto
{
    // Number of Overdue Days
    public int? TotalOverdueDays { get; set; } = OverdueDefaults.DefaultOverdueDays;
    public int? TotalOverdueDaysIs { get; set; } = OverdueDefaults.DefaultMaxOverdueDays;

    // Range of Amounts
    public int? FromSum { get; set; } = OverdueDefaults.DefaultFromSum;
    public int? ToSum { get; set; } = OverdueDefaults.DefaultToSum;
}

или оставить в DTO? Какие подходы предпочтительны и почему?

Несколько странно, что nullable поля имеют дефолтные значения не null. А когда же там вообще null возможен? Когда из базы приходят? А почему дефолтные эти значения в базу не отправились? Странновато. А по сути ну да, "магические числа" - это плохо, хорошо бы их куда-то убирать. В константы, либо вообще в файл настроек и оттуда как-то забирать.

@CrazyElf
Спасибо. Только сейчас заметила что здесь вовсе и не нужен Nullable

Да может и нужен, если таблица в БД живёт давно и там реально есть NULL-ы, а с дефолтными значениями это позже придумали, но по-хорошему я бы тогда в БД тоже на дефолтные значения эти NULL поменял, консистентность лучше когда есть между кодом и БД. А если её нет, то это требует пояснения, почему так получилось.
